# C, Open gl, drawing until another line

Tags: c, opengl

Trying to figure out how to draw that white lines until these red lines:

[image]

I can draw to until green point height's but not red lines.

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what unexpected thing occurred?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without providing a single line of code?

Comment: Ah sorry, i created points and red lines. If you can wait until i reach my home. I can copy my code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, aren't you guys tired about moaning all the time with the typical sentences "what have you tried so far", "we're not here to code for you" and blah blah blah. Either you help and you code it or not... I'm sure the op knows by hearth he didn't research enough about the subject and he's being kind of lazy... so what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little unoptimized example using the fixed function opengl pipeline:

```
#define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS 1
#define NDEBUG 1

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_POINTS 8
#define PROJ_VALUE 40

float points[MAX_POINTS][2];

void init() {
    points[0][0] = 0;
    points[0][1] = 10;
    points[1][0] = 1;
    points[1][1] = 8;
    points[2][0] = 2;
    points[2][1] = 4;
    points[3][0] = 3;
    points[3][1] = 7;
    points[4][0] = 4;
    points[4][1] = 3;
    points[5][0] = 5;
    points[5][1] = 4;
    points[6][0] = 6;
    points[6][1] = 5;
    points[7][0] = 7;
    points[7][1] = 0;
}

float lerp(float x, float a, float b) {
    return x * b + (1 - x) * a;
}

void plot_function(int step_x, int step_y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_POINTS; i++) {
        float x0 = (float)points[i][0] * step_x + step_x;
        float y0 = (float)points[i][1] * step_y;
        float x1 = (float)points[i + 1][0] * step_x + step_x;
        float y1 = (float)points[i + 1][1] * step_y;

        for (int j = 0; j < step_x; j++) {
            float k = (float)j / step_x;

            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2f(x0 + j, 0);
            glVertex2f(x0 + j, lerp(k, y0, y1));
            glEnd();
        }

        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glPointSize(8);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(x0, y0);
        glEnd();

        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(x0, y0);
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glEnd();
    }
}

void display() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, PROJ_VALUE, 0, PROJ_VALUE, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    plot_function(5, 2);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    init();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("StackOverflow gl plotting");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I'll leave to you the exercise to make it beautier (round points, antialiasing, clipping, smooth rendering) and refactor properly the code to be faster&cleaner. Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Brief explanation of the above code:

At the very beginning you'll have some control points (green points). Usually you store these points into an array of floating point values, in the above code they're just stored in a global variable called `points`. To draw these points you'd just need to loop through the array and using the opengl function to draw points, they represent x&y coordinates. You could also draw the white lines from [x,y] to [x,0] easily as well.

Now, the tricky part, how do we draw the intermediate points? What are they actually? First of all, you need to understand what a linear interpolation is, read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), but basically is a formula like `x*b+(1-x)*a`, if you consider x=0 the result will be a, if x=1 the result will be b and if the value is between [0,1] you'll get a value in between a&b. So, in order to calculate the intermediate points you just apply the linear interpolation between the previous&next points, you can see that in the line `glVertex2f(x0 + j, lerp(k, y0, y1))`.

About step_x & step_y arguments, if it's easier for you to understand, replace them with 0 and get rid of them, so you'll understand easily the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Trying to understand. It looks complicated actually .https://pastebin.com/NYsNACqu. I wrote this code segment to create green points and red lines randomised. And sorry for the late coming.

Comment: @BDL I've edited my answer, I had considered the code to be trivial enough for not explaining anything... but you're probably right here, i was assuming some basic here. At the end of the day is just an example of really unoptimized code, you shouldn't neither use the fixed point pipeline nor computing the points on the display loop, so...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is very helpful. I'll try to integrate my randomised points.

Comment: @aqeyndx You're welcome, I see you're new to SO. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.